# How to add back button to system Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Android app that I set to kiosk mode with

```
adb shell
su
pm disable com.android.systemui
```

In this mode the system navigation bar is hidden.
But in some cases I enable the user to open Intent like "Change Network" or "IntentIntegrator" (to scan QR codes).
The problem is that the user doesn't have an way to go back to the app.
When open the "Settings" Intent, I have a "back" (<h;) button at the top left corner. I would like something like that in the other Intents.